# Why is my Systemd service not passing parameters from my EnvironmentFile?

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm new-ish to systemd. I've got a service that's been working fine with the `ExecStart` command line hard-coded. Now I'm trying to parameterize it, and I found `EnvironmentFile` written up online. So I modified my service file as follows (some things obfuscated for privacy):

```
[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/my-service/my-service-systemd.cfg
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/my-service -port=$PORT -log-level=$LOG_LEVEL -creds=$CREDENTIALS_FILE
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID
```

I checked, and the environment file `/etc/my-service/my-service-systemd.cfg` is definitely there:

```
CREDENTIALS_FILE=/etc/my-service/my-service.pwd
LOG_LEVEL=2
PORT=443
```

But when I run the service, it fails, and the logs indicate that all parameters are coming in empty, i.e. the service file is not passing in values from the `EnvironmentFile`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are rules on the expansion of the `$` prefix in `ExecStart` and so on. There is a difference between `$var` and `${var}`. The former will only be interpolated if it occurs as a word on its own (surrounded by whitespace). The latter does not have this restriction. So use, for example,

```
-port=${PORT}
```

The reference for this is under the heading *COMMAND LINES* in [man systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines).

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to file permissions.
See if this fixes it:

```
chown root:root /etc/my-service/my-service-systemd.cfg 
chmod 0640 /etc/my-service/my-service-systemd.cfg
```